# Merge/concatenate unknown amount of byte arrays

Tags: c++, variadic

I can merge/combine/concatenate two arrays with the following function, but how could I rework it to support unknown amount of arrays. In other words a variadic function `Args...`?

```cpp
char* concat(char* a, size_t a_size,
             char* b, size_t b_size) {
    char* c = realloc(a, a_size + b_size);
    memcpy(c + a_size, b,  b_size);  // dest is after "a" data, source is b with b_size
    free(b);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `std::string`? or `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm actually concatenating `std::uint8_t` (byte arrays). They are not strings.

Comment: Soo `std::vector<uint8_t>`? And `uint8_t* + size_t` is `std::span`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I never used std::span. Would you like to write it as a solution?

Comment: It's not a solution - still, you have to write it yourself. But it's easier to manage code using single object, instead of pairs. And still, `free(b)` - it's just easier to use `std::vector`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `span`s and `vector`s, you could write this as:

```cpp
std::vector<std::byte> Concat(std::span<std::byte> a)
{
    return std::vector<std::byte>(a.data(), a.data() + a.size());
}

template<typename... Args>
std::vector<std::byte> Concat(std::span<std::byte> a, Args... args)
{
  auto vec = std::vector<std::byte>(a.data(), a.data() + a.size());
  auto concat = Concat(args...);
  vec.insert(vec.end(), concat.begin(), concat.end());
  
  return vec;
}
```

Note that you will need a C++20 compliant compiler to be able to use `span`. The latest versions of GCC, Clang, and MSVC are all supported.

Comment: `(vec.insert(vec.end(), args.begin(), args.end()), ...);` would avoid some allocations, and requires less instantiations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something like this would work for you? This should work with C++11 too I think and can be adapted for `std::span` if required, I believe. It just allocates memory once and then subsequently copies each memory block provided to `concat` into this allocated block, doing away with the need for any re-allocations.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
size_t concatSize(T* arr, size_t len) {
    return len;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
size_t concatSize(T* arr, size_t len, Args... args) {
    return len + concatSize(args...);
}

template <typename T>
void copyMem(T* res, T* arr, size_t len) {
    memcpy(res, arr, len);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void copyMem(T* res, T* arr, size_t len, Args... args) {
    memcpy(res, arr, len);
    copyMem((T*)((char*)res + len), args...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
std::pair<T*, size_t> concat(T* arr, size_t len, Args... args) {
    static_assert(sizeof... (Args)%2 == 0, "Not even number of arguments!");
    auto size = concatSize(arr, len, args...);
    T* result = (T*)malloc(size);
    copyMem(result, arr, len, args...);
    return std::make_pair(result, size);
}

int main() {
    {
        char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
        char b[] = {'d', 'e', 'f'};
        char c[] = {'g', 'h', 'i'};
        auto result = concat(a, sizeof a, b, sizeof b, c, sizeof c);
        //Don't use regular printf %s since it's not a C-string!
        for(int i = 0; i < result.second; ++i) {
            std::printf("%c ", result.first[i]);
        }
        std::printf("\n");
        free(result.first);
    }
    {
        int a[] = {'1', '2', '3'};
        int b[] = {'4', '5', '6'};
        int c[] = {'7', '8', '9'};
        auto result = concat(a, sizeof( a), b, sizeof( b), c, sizeof( c));
        char* x = (char*)result.first;
        for(int i = 0; i < result.second; ++i) {
            std::printf("%c ", x[i]);
        }
        std::printf("\n");
        free(result.first);       
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/bPb3nM7sa):

```
a b c d e f g h i 
1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
```